# Running the atom-editor with the hydrogen package on mac os x with Anaconda3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, atom-editor, hydrogen

I hope this is the right place to look for help. If not so forgive me since I am new to this but I want to start learning python for usage with the RaspberryPI. I read that it makes more sense to start with python3 rather than python2. So I installed Anaconda3 on mac os x and want to use the atom editor with the hydrogen package to start my adventure.
I understand the requirement that I need python2.x to run hydrogen, but I want to use python3.x for learning programming. I thought I might get around this issue by creating an environment with anaconda using python2.x,

```
conda create --name python2 python=2
```

and then switch to it by

```
source activate python2
```

however, while this creates and switches to the desired environment, atom and hydrogen still seem to try use python3 when I start atom in the environment python2 from the terminal. Does anyone here know how to correctly set up what I described above?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `jupyter kernelspec list` when your python2 environment is activated; if that doesn't list the Python 2 Jupyter kernel (possibly because the python2 environment doesn't contain Jupyter but the root Python 3 environment does), atom will not be able to find it (in which case you can manually configure the Kernel Spec setting in atom to specify where the kernel is located).